# Swift: why 'subscript(var digitIndex: Int) -> Int' is a valid function signature?

Tags: swift

This piece of code comes from Swift documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html

```
extension Int {
    subscript(var digitIndex: Int) -> Int {
        var decimalBase = 1
            while digitIndex > 0 {
                decimalBase *= 10
                --digitIndex
            }
            return (self / decimalBase) % 10
    }
}
```

Apparently `var` is a reserved word, so why it is legal to declare: `subscript(var digitIndex: Int) -> Int`?

If I change the signature to `subscript(#digitIndex: Int) -> Int`, I will get this compiler error:

[image]

My questions are:

1) why the signature is valid?

2) why my change causes an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring a function argument with `var` means that it can be modified, is not a constant.  In your case, without using `var`, you had a constant argument but you attempted to decrement it.  Thus the error.

Your two cases are:

```
func foo (x: int) { /* x is a constant, like `let x: int` */ }

func foo (var x: int) { /* x is not a constant */ }
```